# Limit number of threads on ProducerTemplate asyncSend call

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

In a processor in a camel route I am retrieving data with a cursor and sending it to a route that sends it in batches to the database. The current ProducerTemplate sends the data in a synchronous manner.

```
ProducerTemplate template = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();

do {
   template.send(START_ROUTE_TO_DATABASE, exchange.copy());
   } while new data is retrieved
```

When I make the process faster by making the call asynchronous `template.asyncSend(START_ROUTE_TO_DATABASE, exchange.copy());` the app still runs, but it start consuming a lot of memory. I want to limit this memory use, by limiting the number of threads that get created when `template.asyncSend()` is called. What is the best way to limit the number of threads? Is there another way to limit memory use that I am overlooking?